# ant javascript failonerror

Tags: javascript, ant, failonerror

I have an ant task that includes embedded javascript.  I'd like to have the target fail or succeed based on some logic I run in the javascript:

```
<target name="analyze">
    <script language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
            importClass(java.io.File);
            importClass(java.io.FileReader)
            importClass(java.io.BufferedReader)

            String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) {
                return (this.indexOf(str) === 0);
            }

            String.prototype.endsWith = function(str) {
                var lastIndex = this.lastIndexOf(str);
                return (lastIndex != -1) && (lastIndex + str.length == this.length);
            }

            //setup the source directory
            srcDir = project.getProperty("MY_HOME") + "/foo/src";

            if(srcDir.startsWith("/foo") { 
            //TARGET SHOULD PASS
            } else { 
            //TARGET SHOULD FAIL
            }

    ]]>
    </script>
</target>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make Ant exit via the Exit API, but that throws a build exception which will lead to a messy stack trace.  The cleanest method would be to set a property in the javascript then test it using the [`fail` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html):

Javascript:

```
project.setProperty( "javascript.fail.message", "There was a problem" );
```

Ant, immediately after the script task:

```
<fail if="javascript.fail.message" message="${javascript.fail.message}" />
```

Comment: Martin, that works exactly the way I want it to.  You've answered all of my questions brilliantly, I stand in awe.

Comment: @Amir - you're too kind.  Glad to help, but sorry I didn't get around to writing an answer earlier - work got in the way.

Comment: Out of curiosity Martin, if I wanted to re-write this script in Java, would it be hard?  Is there a tutorial somewhere?  My googling hasn't resulted in a lot of good results.

Answer (score 3):

Another target:

```
<target name="failme"><fail/></target>
```

Script:

```
`project.executeTarget("failme");`
```

Not tested. [Documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html)

Comment: This seems clever.  When I tested it I got something like: WrappedException: no message.  Any idea what to do with that?

Comment: This seems to work but throws a ScriptException.  I'd like for the script to execute without exceptions, and the target itself to fail.  Is there a way to propogate a boolean back up to ant from my script?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it completely in one JavaScript block.

```
    <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
                failTask = project.createTask("fail");
                failTask.setMessage("I have failed");
                failTask.perform();
    ]]>
    </script>
```